# How to sent SMS alert when my server goes down?

Tags: network-monitoring

Previously, we used Total Network Monitor in our organizations to monitor all the systems and their services by adding Mail Alerts.

Now we are looking for some kind of SMS message alerts when the server system goes down. We have an SMS API's and gateways but we are unable to figure out the solutions to fix.

Answer (score 2):

There are bunch of softwares avaiable to do that. you can find their features opt to your needs.

https://www.bijk.com/server/showServers [it is an open source it has SMS+Email and more]

http://www.serverscheck.com/monitoring_software/frontend_sms.asp

http://www.gfi.com/products-and-solutions/network-security-solutions/gfi-network-server-monitor

http://www.paessler.com/server_monitoring_software

https://www.pingdom.com/enterprise/

Answer (score 2):

One of the "Industry Standard" pieces of software for doing monitoring is [Nagios.](http://www.nagios.org/) (and its free) You can clip in a whole lot of plugins for this - including writing your own if need be, and setting various triggers and criteria to send to email, sms and other notifications.  It does have a learning curve but it is worth it - Of-course, it assumes you have a PC you can use to monitor your network - presumeably at a different site (depending on your needs).

I rolled a small script to send SMS messages from the command line which I then used with Nagios to send out outage notifications through a directly attached USB dongle - http://www.my.host.net.nz/blog/2013/07/quick-script-to-send-smss-under-linux/ thus eliminating the need for an external SMS provider and reachable Internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [pingdoms](http://pingdom.com) services. They will monitor the machine you request and send you immediate messages when a machine goes down or comes up, plus it is really easy to use. They even have a free starter level (which is the one I use)

Answer (score 0):

try to use
[watchmyservice.com](http://watchmyservice.com/)

there are free sms packs. Simple. Convenient.

You can add a server entity by it's ip address. And you can create the strategy entity - the monitoring algorithm of your servers. After registration you will have 10 free sms